# Entity framework core, update-database don't take account of attributes

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I have an entity `PersonEntity` with some attribute

```
    public class PersonEntity
    {

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Key]
        public int Id{ get; set; }
    }
```

when I do `update-database -verbose` the database and the table are generated but without take account of the attributes. There is varchar(MAX) for `FirstName` and `LastName` in the database and it's nullable.

I tried with fluent API (I removed the attributes)

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<PersonEntity>()
        .ToTable(nameof(this.Customer))
        .HasKey(e => e.Id);

    modelBuilder.Entity<PersonEntity>()
        .Property(t => t.LastName)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasMaxLength(50);

    modelBuilder.Entity<PersonEntity>()
        .Property(t => t.FirstName)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasMaxLength(50);

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

but same result.

Any idea why?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Update-Database*: Executes the last migration file created by the Add-Migration command and applies changes to the database schema

Whenever you change the domain classes, execute `Add-Migration` with the name parameter to create a new migration file and then execute the Update-Database command to apply the changes to the database schema.
[Ref](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-based-migration-in-code-first.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Every time you change entities, you need to create new migrations again by running  `Add-Migration` in order to have then applied before running `update-database` command.

For more details just refer to this official documentation of **Migrations**:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=vs#customize-migration-code